# What is the maximum size of files/attachment in salesforce that can be created by external systems

Tags: api, rest, attachment, external-services

What is the maximum size of files/attachment can be created under an object record in salesforce by an external system?
As per documentation its 2 GB for files and 25 MB for attachments.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_size_limits.htm&type=5

Will it be same when an external system trying to create files/attachment in salesforce using salesforce REST API
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_list.htm#inserting_a_contentversion

Answer (score 3):

Yes, those limits are globally applied. Note that some APIs will have a lower limit, such as a ContentVersion created by SOAP (which will be limited to about 37MB because of the 50MB payload limit), but using specified APIs, such as creating a ContentVersion using [REST API with form/multipart](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm) will support 2GB file sizes.